# Move a div inside a div with another div already in it

Tags: html, css

I hope it didn't sound too confusing, but basically what I want is to move that div with the buttons, highlighted in green, to the place highlighted in red, with the image on the left and the buttons on the center:

[image]

I searched in every place on the internet and all the solutions don't put me the div in the center, only on the far right or in any other place where is not supposed to be, so I'm hoping someone here could help me with this!

This is the HTML I have on that top part:

```
<body>
    <div id="topback">
        <div class="caixa_botoes">
            <button id="bot1" type="button">Resultados</button>
            <button id="bot1" type="button">Rankings</button>
            <button id="bot1" type="button">Partidas</button>
            <button id="bot1" type="button">Noticias</button>
        </div>
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png">

    </div>
```

And this is the CSS i have:

```
#topback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #2a4158; 
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo{
  margin-top: 0.3%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 4.5%;
  border: 4px solid #22272c;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.caixa_botoes{
  margin-top: 0.3%;
  display: block;
}

#bot1{
  border: none;
  color: #2a4158;
  background-color: #8c9ea3;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I hope that someone can help me, thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? Also, ID values must be unique. An ID doesn't identify anything if it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to use on the parent div:

```
display: flex
```

https://flexboxfroggy.com/ < Learn how to use flexbox here using this fun game, and you will be able to create any layout you want then :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start by adjusting the order of your HTML elements if that's an option:

```
<div id="topback">
   <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
   <div class="caixa_botoes">
      <button id="bot1" type="button">Resultados</button>
      <button id="bot1" type="button">Rankings</button>
      <button id="bot1" type="button">Partidas</button>
      <button id="bot1" type="button">Noticias</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Those elements will appear in order so the image should be to the left (above in the the HTML) anyway. And then there are a lot of ways to proceed.

Does the `#topback` need to be `position: absolute`? That may be complicating things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add the following:

```
.caixa_botoes{
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

and

```
#bot1{
  padding: 15px 1.5%;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  width: 21%;
}
```